# TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 Migration and SharePoint Content database

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010, tfs-2015

What is the proper procedure for dealing with the SharePoint TFS content database?  We have migrated our TFS installation from TFS2010 to TFS2015 and are really unsure how to properly handle SharePoint.

Under TFS2010, we had our SharePoint content databases hosted in SharePoint Foundation 2010.  As part of the TFS2015 migration we installed SharePoint Foundation 2013 and re-attached the 2010 content database, but did not update the look and feel to SharePoint 2013. Everything seems work under the old look and feel, however if we do upgrade the look and feel to SharePoint 2013, some of the buttons on the widgets stop working. For example: clicking the **New Work Item** and the selected any type of work item does not do anything.

Are we supposed to leave the look and feel alone, and in the old Sharepoint 2010 format , or are we missing a step? Online documentation seems to be sparse on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either to use the same SharePoint site for TFS that you have right now or you'll need to **upgrade your SharePoint instance first**.

- TFS 2010 supported Office SharePoint Server 2007 (Standard,
  Enterprise) and Windows SharePoint Services 3.0.
- TFS 2015 supports SharePoint 2010 and 2013 (Foundation, Standard,
  Enterprise).

After upgrading your SharePoint instance, you'll need to install TFS 2015 on it and then configure SharePoint Extensions.

Here's a guide on how to migrate TFS databases including SharePoint databases in detailed steps:

[Migrating Team Foundation Server Databases](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2014/05/15/migrating-team-foundation-server-databases/)

This is also a related situation for your reference:

[Migration Update from Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2013 to TFS 2015 (With Reporting and SharePoint)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/09/30/migration-update-from-team-foundation-server-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2015-with-reporting-and-sharepoint/)

---

**Update**

> **Things That Don't Work Anymore After I Migrated to SharePoint 2013**
>
> The change from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 is even more
>   radical then it was from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010. This time
>   we’re switching to HTML5 - which was built to work easily on all
>   browsers and even other devices. In today's world, it was inevitable.
>
> There is also a big change in the way SharePoint shows us its content;
>   Web Parts no longer use tables, for the most part, and the use of XSLT
>   has been replaced by Display Templates. This means almost all your
>   branded Web Parts and Content Query styles will no longer work. ....
>
> Source Link: [What might not work so well anymore after the
>   migration](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/not-working-after-sharepoint-migration-to-2013)

And according to [TFS 2013 Upgrade - SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 Failure](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88643/tfs-2013-upgrade-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-failure). SharePoint 2013 has two modes (hives), 2010 (v14) and 2013 (v15). Apparently,a new 2013 installation mostly only installs v15 features. You can also give a try with this.

I don’t think all your old look and feel will be functional in 2013, **given the huge changes in the UI**. But since that site’s content and TFS function is fully browsable and usable as it is now with old look, at least you can still remain in 2010 mode.

Comment: thanks for providing that information; it is a good recap of the process we used. We have successfully migrated the TFS and SharePoint databases; however our specific issue is with the look and feel of the SharePoint Team project portal sites.  If we leave them in the legacy SharePoint look and feel, everything works great. If however we upgrade them to the new SharePoint 2013 look and feel, the TFS specific web parts stop functioning.  Neither of your linked articles touched on this topic.  Are we stuck with the old look and feel or is there a manual process to update the sites?

Comment: If you can work well with old mode. Seems this issue do not belong to the category of TFS. It's more related to the migration of sharepoint.

Comment: However,  I still find some articles may help you. `The change from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 is even more radical. This time we’re switching to HTML5 . ...` More details please see my update. And according to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88643/tfs-2013-upgrade-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-failure  SharePoint 2013 has two modes (hives), 2010 (v14) and 2013 (v15). Apparently,a new 2013 installation mostly only installs v15 features. You can also give a try with this.